# How to share a torrent in Ubuntu server

Tags: 11.10, sharing, bittorrent

I have uploaded a huge ISO file and I wish to share it in a torrent site (I will not name names because then there will be no soup for me). How can I share this torrent file to others.

Using Ubuntu server 11.10 and there is yet no torrent manager in the server. Am looking for something terminal related (since there is no gui).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The torrent file is actually shared by just sending them the .torrent that your client created.
However, after creating the .torrent you'd need to upload it to a tracker or specify a tracker when creating the .torrent, alternatively have your client broadcast via DHT. Otherwise there is no way for your client to be part of a swarm that other clients could pick up.

If you're looking for a CLI torrent client, I'd suggest `transmission-cli` which is quite basic and should get the job done. `deluged` is personal favorite and handles large numbers of torrents quite nicely.

Comment: Also consider rtorrent. I use it on my VPS outside of work to download then FTP the files in.